# Class Instantiation, and variable sharing for abstract/static classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class

Simple example of my problem:

```
class AbstractService:
    subscribers = []

    @classmethod
    def subscribe(cls, service):
        service.subscribers.append(cls)

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def notify(cls, payload):
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{cls.__name__} not implemented notify()")


class ServiceA(AbstractService):

    @classmethod
    def notify(cls, payload):
        pass


class ServiceB(AbstractService):

    @classmethod
    def notify(cls, payload):
        pass


ServiceB.subscribe(ServiceA)

ServiceA.notify({'message': 'hello'})
```

The issue is that all services in this instance will share subscribers, hence my solution was to create a function that returns the abstract service as such:

```
def get_abstract_service():
        
    class AbstractService:
        subscribers = []
    
        @classmethod
        def subscribe(cls, service):
            service.subscribers.append(cls)
    
        @classmethod
        @abstractmethod
        def notify(cls, payload):
            raise NotImplementedError(f"{cls.__name__} not implemented notify()")

    return AbstractService
class ServiceA(get_abstract_service()):

    @classmethod
    def notify(cls, payload):
        pass


class ServiceB(get_abstract_service()):

    @classmethod
    def notify(cls, payload):
        pass


ServiceB.subscribe(ServiceA)

ServiceA.notify({'message': 'hello'})
```

This now works because subscribers are unique to each class inheriting the abstract service.

**Issues**

1. Is this correct for python, or is the pattern wrong if so what would be
   the norm in this situation
2. How do I handle typing for AbstractService if my solution is correct
   (for any function that requires that type to be passed to it)

Comment: The easy fix would be to give each subclass its own `subscribers = []` line.  If you want to automate the process, give the base class a `__init_subclass__` method that initializes the list.  Your "solution" destroys the inheritance relationship between classes: each subclass derives from an *entirely separate* base class, that all happen to have the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be something like this that I was missing, but just couldn't find it, my solution just felt wrong :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would approach it like this:

```
from __future__ import annotations


class AbstractService:
    subscribers: list[AbstractService]

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kw)
        cls.subscribers = []
```

it sets a new `subscribers` instance on each class after creation.

edit: additionally this handles typing for you as well by using `from __future__ import annotations`

e.g.

```
class C:
    def f(self) -> C:
        ...
```

Comment: Just one small recommendation: call `super().__init_subclass__(**__)` as well. You're accepting keyword arguments so that they can be passed on to the `__init_subclass__` method that expects them.